# An easy way to check if textboxes has values?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox

So im having some fun trying to improve my c# while making a basic converter for windows phone 7.

The thing is I have 4 textfields but only 2 are required and allowed to fill in, if any more then two are filled there should be a warning saying that you are supposed to fill out two and only two fields and not perform the action.

I was thinking of either a loop or if theres a way to count textboxes that have values and a boolean thats true or false depending on if a value is 2 or greater then two then allowing calculations based on that but im not sure on how to implement this.

Sorry if its a basic question, I do have soem knowledge on programming but im still at a basic level and im trying to learn the more advanced and efficient ways of doing things.

Comment: No sorry cant say that I am. Ive been tinkering some more and Ive added a counter variable so on text_textchanged if the text length is > 0 i add one to the counter and if the counter is greater then or less then 2 an error appears but this is flawed aswell because when i press calculate it populates the other two fields making counter = 4 and it fails :p.

Comment: You could try to create 4 booleans which are true if your textbox has a value or not and in every textchange you take a look at the 4 values and act accordingly to set the textbox value or inform the user that only two are allowed. In the Calculate if you wanna set all textboxes you would need to remove the textchange eventhandler for that time.

Comment: Yea I just started trying with 4 booleans, but im checking if 2 are true then I lock the other 2 until text in one of the 2 boxes that are active has a text.lenght = 0 and see how it works, might be easier so its not possible to enter text into more then 2 boxes

Answer (score 0):

if you are using WPF, you can may use of two way binding with properties, then check for these values.